# cassandra client-to-node encryption with cassandra-stress

Tags: cassandra-stress

I have enabled client-to-node and node-to-node encryption in my cassandra cluster.   What optionial parameters do I need to pass to get cassandra-stress to work?

I'm am striking out finding any examples or good documentation on using this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already found the answer, but I will answer for those who might come looking.

Try:

```
cassandra-stress write -node 127.0.0.1 -transport truststore=/path/to/cluster/truststore.jks truststore-password=mytruststorepassword -mode native cql3 user=myuser password=mypassword
```

I found [this](https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/2016/02/08/connecting-to-a-cassandra-cluster-using-tls-ssl/) blog post very useful.

This was not available in Apache Cassandra v2.1, if you want to learn more on how this was implemented then look at this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9325) post